# nodejs/javascript remove URL from string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Some users using URLs (Domains) in there usernames.
They are sometimes much different, so i want to filter them out in there name

I can `str.replace` urls, if i know the urls, but there much different so i think regex is, how it works, but i try so much, but doesnt get any results...

I hope someone can help me.

I found that Regex for PHP but i need something for NodeJS / Javascript.

```
 $regex = '/^(.*?)';
 $regex .= "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
 $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
 $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP 
 $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
 $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
 $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
 $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor 
 $regex .= '(.*?)$/i';
```

A username looks like

```
USERNAME Google.com
```

but can also

```
USERNAME www.GOOGLE.com
```

or

```
USERNAME GOOGLE.GG
```

Comment: You could block `.` in username. Even with regex users could do something like `google(.)com, google . com` etc.

Comment: What you mean? If i replace "." in the name, than it looks Like `USERNAME GOOGLEcom` Not really better :/

Comment: Just don't let them use `.` in their username when registering. It's just a suggestion, not the only solution. You could create a massive regex to check different combinations.

Comment: I use an API. I cannot check or let them create usernames. I get this from Login API

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to check for URL. It's basic. You can extend it if you need.

`((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?`

https://regex101.com/r/fMAMkA/1

Comment: Hm thanks. But how to use it? Can you create a JSFiddle with my example `USERNAME Google.com`? I tried but not working https://jsfiddle.net/u3bo9kdf/1/

Comment: Remove `^` from regex to not look from start of a line. https://jsfiddle.net/0y2ftk8a/